# How to enable go.vim by default (automatically)?

Tags: vim, go

The instructions on the Vim site says to just put the file in the /syntax folder. This works all right and well. But, for me to use the syntax I must set the following

```
:set syntax=go
```

Every *single* time. So, I know I am doing something wrong. I just don't know what.

Here are some things from looking around,

My HTML5 syntax set is from Rodrigo's HTML5 [omnicomplete function and syntax vimball file](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim#readme). Though this uses some installation script to get it going.

As far as I can tell this would be my first manual adding of syntax file.

Also, my `VIMRUNTIME` is not set, well because there is no syntax.vim file, so from reading the documentation I see it checks for files via synload.vim

I even read the "[Making Your Own Syntax Files](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html)" section, which says that same as above with the `syntax=go` option. Am I supposed to be detecting the .go filetype as described in [new filetype section](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype)?

**How can I enable syntax highlighting for GO by default?**

This is for Mac Snow Leopard.

<sub>I don't think it is this complicated but I decided to leave all the different documentation I skimmed. GO and Vim say to just add the file. But it is definitely not detecting it automatically</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using filetype detection in your `~/.vimrc` file with the following line:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

then you can place the file in the following folder:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/go.vim
```

or for windows

```
~/vimfiles/...
```

For the filetype detection to work, would would want the autocmd in a file in the ftdetect folder:

```
~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim
```

and the contents would be:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.go set filetype=go
```

Comment: Ok so with the ftdetect, from now on, the procedure would be to add the file to syntax folder and update with a new autocmd for every new undetected file?

Comment: You can also use the following Github mirror of the official vim scripts for Go, allowing for easy installation/updates via Vundle, etc: https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang

Answer (score 2):

Use autocmd:
`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go setlocal filetype=go`